# website wordpress disappeared after changing permissions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permissions

I'm in troubles with my wordpress site
yesterday my site disappeared suddenly...I watched only the message "error 403 forbidden access, litespeed...". My provider said I had to put a .htaccess file in my directory with this code: mod_security2.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off

I did it but nothing changed. But they wrote also that I had to change the permissions in 755.

I did it again with cyberduck but (when I was changing the permission of the mail folder "public_html") I pushed (my mistake) on the button "change the permission also in all file of the folder". I stopped after few seconds but then I watched on my homepage only my directory....with a list of all file (wp-admin, wp-login and so on..." dimension of the files  0 k and there's written near every file "last modified 1970")
if I write the name of my site with /wp-admin I see "error 404"....my provider of course said that I made a mistake changing the permission of the files and that I had to upload entirely the site again...I don't know if the site is down because of a changing of permissions in every file of wordpress...is there a way to set the right permission so that the site is again visible?
thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple single command to roll back the permissions you've changed. You'll have to do it manually. You can use the same tool you were using to update permissions in bulk but being extremely careful this time.

The following applies to a default Wordpress installation:

> All folder permissions should be set to 755. Files should be set to 644. Files that you want to edit in the WordPress Theme editor should be 666. **Never use 777** for WordPress permissions.

If you have command-line SSH (secure shell) access to your web host have a look at the following [article](http://wordpress.shadowlantern.com/how-to-fix-permissions-on-files-and-directories/). You can also ask your tech support to execute these commands for you and check if it resolves your problem.

```
find ~/public_html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ~/public_html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Once you get your site up, check if you may have missed or misconfigured permissions for any files using the [WordPress Security Scan](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-security-scan/) plugin. This would check for insecure file permissions among other things like passwords and database security. Here's a screenshot of it in action:

[image: WP Security Scan's file permissions check]